# Bar symbol with subscript

Tags: math-mode

I want to type Y bar with subscript as shown in following code. However, when I try to use \bar , the Bar symbol is going beyond Y. I want to limit the bar symbol to Y.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
    $\bar{\bm{Y_{rss}}}$ 
\end{document}
```

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Perhaps `\bar{\bm{Y}}_{rss}`? Or `\bar{\bm{Y}}_{\bm{rss}}` if you need also the subscript to be bold (which I don't believe, probably it should even be `\bar{\bm{Y}}_{\mathrm{rss}}`).

Comment: \bar{\bm{Y}}_{rss} solve my problem. Yes I do not want my subscript to be bold. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the \bar{\bm{Y}}_{rss} solve the problem of the OP.